# Maven-encrypted password suddenly not working anymore? Any clues?

Tags: maven

We again and again encounter the situation that our local builds suddenly fail to access our repository (Artifactory/JFrog) with "Authentication failed for https:///.../<some-arbitrary .pom or .jar filename here> 401 Unauthorized" errors.

As we found out by some lengthy trial and error in such situations we need to re-encrypt our (same) password anew (using `mvn --encrypt-password <password>`) and need to put the newly generated output into our settings.xml file (or - as most of us do - update a corresponding environment variable with the new value).

But why is that so? These passwords seem to be invalidated seemingly at random. Some people haven't seen that effect for >1 year. Some have it every other week (and that gets mighty annoying!).
What could be causing this? Is there some info stored somewhere that could be accidentally deleted again and again or what mechanism could be causing this?

Addendum: Maven and Java version info:

```
C:> mvn -version
executing: "C:\Program Files\Apache\Maven\bin\mvn.cmd"
========================
JAVA_HOME=C:\Program Files\Java\jdk-1.8.0
JAVACMD=C:\Program Files\Java\jdk-1.8.0\bin\java.exe
========================
Apache Maven 3.6.3 (cecedd343002696d0abb50b32b541b8a6ba2883f)
Maven home: C:\Program Files\Apache\Maven\bin\..
Java version: 1.8.0_292, vendor: AdoptOpenJDK, runtime: C:\Program Files\Java\jdk-1.8.0\jre
Default locale: en_US, platform encoding: Cp1252
OS name: "windows 10", version: "10.0", arch: "amd64", family: "windows"
```

Comment: First which version of Maven, JDK etc. you are using...